# How can I control a 240v single phase with a separate 240v phase?

Tags: electrical

I don't have much understanding of phases. Basically there are 2  different power lines named A and B. When A is on I want B on. When A is off B turns off.  A should be used to control use of electricity via B.

I don't know whether such a device already exists. Or can I use logic gates to build one? Any idea how it can be done safely without mixing the phases? Is there any sensor out there that can sense whether a is on an then in turn open a relay for b and same when off?

Comment: We don't mix legs but here is how we get different voltages. a to neutral is 120v,  b to neutral is 120v,  a to b is 240v. Relays can do what you want all answered below.

Comment: Is this in North America, or in the rest of the world?  Is it residential voltage?

Answer (score 4):

Relay is in your question, and Relay is the answer.

(Amazon link because I was there xmas shopping..)

A relay [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008MPKFM8) has a coil voltage of 220v and is also capable of switching a 220v load.  The coil would be connected to circuit A, and the load/circuit B would be connected to the switched side.

Now, you'll have to select a relay for the size load you have and the type of terminals you want to use, but I believe a relay will do just what you need.

I have a set of relays that control my Christmas lights.  I have the coil side (120v) wired into the light on my porch, and that controls the heavier 20A 120v load circuit that powers the lights.  The light duty programmable light switch for the porch light now controls the 20A of lights.